# "Last Logged in: Never (Offline)" for customers who have logged in but not recently

Tags: customer, ce-1.9.1.0, login

This shows in Customer View for any customer who hasn't logged in recently but who **has actually logged in** (e.g. last week or a few days a go). So it is definitely not "Never" and one would expect to see the actual last login date-time.

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be caused by Creare SEO extension which has a setting: **Performance Cleanup > Clean Log entries in DB** which also truncates the `log_customer` db table.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to make sure logs are enabled in Admin under

> **Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System -> Log -> Enable Log should be set to YES**